# How to use template literals for concatenation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use template literals in code but it's not working.

```
let myData =
        (myNewData[0].checked ? Enum.ONE.concat(',') : '') +
        (myNewData[1].checked ? Enum.TWO.concat(',') : '') +
        (myNewData[2].checked ? Enum.THREE : '');
    myData = myData.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
```

I want to check if first or second or third is checked then I should get result with comma separated like - `One,Two,Three`.

It is all working fine. But I am optimizing the code & want to remove concat with Template Literals, How can I do it ?

I tried this also -

```
let myData = (myNewData[0].checked ? `$(Enum.ONE) , $(myNewData[1].checked) ? `Enum.TWO , `(myNewData[2].checked ? Enum.THREE)
    myData = myData.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
```

How can I optimize this code as I am getting the error while using template literals (back tick). I am new in using template literals, Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: Use `${}` with curly brackets (`{` `}`) instead of parenthesis

Comment: Use `backticks` and `${}`

Answer (score 2):

Since each item in the `Enum` is tied to an element in the `myNewData` array, consider changing it to be an array of strings instead of an object of strings. Then you can filter the array by whether the `myNewData` at the same index is checked, then join by commas:

```
const TEXTS = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
const output = TEXTS
  .filter((_, i) => myNewData[i].checked)
  .join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use curly brackets ${ }  instead of parentheses $( ) inside your [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: I tried but getting error. Can you paste here what exactly should I do ?

Comment: I understand this isn't strictly a solution to your template literal question, however, as you're requiring commas between the words I don't think a template literal is your best option here. I'd suggest you would be better [pushing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to an array and then [joining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array with commas.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way to use template literals for concatenation in Javascript.

```
const a = `${myNewData[0].checked ? Enum.ONE: ''}${myNewData[1].checked ? `, ${Enum.TWO}`: ''}${myNewData[2].checked ? `, ${Enum.THREE}`: ''}`
```

On the other hand, there is more "clean" ways to do that...